# Do you write "AT 123.com", or "ON 123.com"? US English

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, american-english, prepositional-phrases, style-manuals

**US English**

I have read other answers on this very question, and no one seems to be able to come up with a clear cut grammatically correct solution.

For a **website/platform** is it:

**A)** At 123.com, you can read articles, listen to music, and much more.

OR

**B)** On 123.com, you can read articles, listen to music, and much more.

I would appreciate it if someone could provide an answer, **"A"** or **"B"**, and why your choice is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The truth is that it's both.

When you're talking about a ***specific place,*** the correct preposition to use is ***at.*** For example, you might say to someone, "Meet you ***at*** the cafe."

When you're talking about a ***relative place,*** the preposition you'd use depends on what you're describing. If, for example, you consider 123.com a ***platform*** of sorts (which some web services are so called, for example, facebook, as a social media platform),  the preposition can be ***on*** instead.

So really, the nuance is whether you're talking about the network location (***at***) or the platform it serves, if any (***on***).

Comment: Thank you! Everyone who has ever struggled with this, the answer is "B," as it is a website (platform.)